# SQL Server 2008: TOP 10 and distinct together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As the title says, I'm using SQL Server 2008. Apologies if this question is very basic. I've only been using SQL for a few days. Right now I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.id, pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val

from dm.labs pl
join mas_data.patients p    
  on pl.id = p.id
  where pl.nm like '%LDL%'
  and val is not null
```

What I want to do is use select top n together with distinct values in the id column. Searching through some forums says to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 ...
```

but when I replace the first line with

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 p.id, pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val
```

I get the same results as without the word distinct. What should I be doing to only get to filter out duplicate id entries?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to state your question more explicitly.  If you have three rows with p.id = 1, then which row do you want?  The one with the highest or lowest pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val, some combination, or something else entirely?  SQL can't apply DISTINCT() this way, but there are ways to get one row per p.id.  You just need to define the requirements, and we can help...

Comment: Is patients.ID a primary key?

Comment: ***Look below the accepted answer to see how to use `TOP 10` and `DISTINCT` together***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easy option is to use group by and select min/max for all other fields

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    p.id, 
    max(pl.nm),
    max(pl.val),
    max(pl.txt_val)
from 
    dm.labs pl
join 
    mas_data.patients p    
on 
    pl.id = p.id
  where 
    pl.nm like '%LDL%'
and 
    val is not null
group by 
    p.id
```

This can get quite tedious for wide table so the other option is to use rank over and partiion

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    p.id, 
     pl.nm, 
     pl.val, 
   pl.txt_val, 
    rank() over(partition by p.id order by p.id) as Rank
from 
    dm.labs pl
join 
    mas_data.patients p    
on 
    pl.id = p.id
  where 
    pl.nm like '%LDL%'
and 
    val is not null
and
    Rank = 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is allowed. You can't reference columns created in the SELECT list in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Check out this answer by Halim just below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642799/4212710

Comment: `The easy option`

Comment: this is a hack , at best , as mentioned before the correct answer is below https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642799/183174

Answer (score 156):

Try

```
SELECT TOP 10 distinct MyId FROM sometable;
```

Comment: Just had to switch them around. Very nice.

Comment: Thank god I kept scrolling after the green check mark.

Comment: too many overly complicated answers on SO sometimes, my god.... Just use this people!!!

Comment: This doesn't work on MS SQL: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'.` But `SELECT distinct TOP 10` works

Answer (score 27):

```
select top 10 p.id from(select distinct p.id  from tablename)tablename
```

Comment: simple and elegant.  Should be the top voted answer.

Comment: I don't think this works, as distinct orders ids ascending

Answer (score 5):

Few ideas:

1. You have quite a few fields in your select statement. Any value being different from another will make that row distinct.
2. TOP clauses are usually paired with WHERE clauses. Otherwise TOP doesn't mean much. Top of what? The way you specify "top of what" is to sort by using WHERE
3. It's entirely possible to get the same results even though you use TOP and DISTINCT and WHERE. Check to make sure that the data you're querying is indeed capable of being filtered and ordered in the manner you expect.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 p.id, pl.nm -- , pl.val, pl.txt_val
FROM dm.labs pl
JOIN mas_data.patients p    
on pl.id = p.id
where pl.nm like '%LDL%'
and val is not null
ORDER BY pl.nm
```

Note that i commented out some of the SELECT to limit your result set and DISTINCT logic.

Answer (score 3):

```
select top 10 * from
(
    select distinct p.id, ....
)
```

will work.

Comment: he wants distinct values for ID's as far as i can see, so this won't work

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but figured I would throw in what came up with since I just ran into this same issue. It may not be efficient, but I believe it gets the job done.

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.id, pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val
INTO #yourTempTable
from dm.labs pl 
join mas_data.patients p on pl.id = p.id   
where pl.nm like '%LDL%' and val is not null

select p.id, pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val
from #yourTempTable
where id IN (select distinct id from #yourTempTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

well I wouldn't have expected it, but Halim's 
    SELECT distinct TOP 10 MyId FROM sometable

is functionally identical to Vaishnavi Kumar's
    select top 10 p.id from(select distinct p.id  from tablename)tablename

```
create table #names ([name] varchar(10))
insert into #names ([name]) values ('jim')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('jim')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('bob')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('mary')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('bob')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('mary')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('john')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('mark')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('matthew')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('luke')
insert into #names ([name]) values ('peter')

select distinct top 5 [name] from #names

select top 5 * from (select distinct [name] from #names) subquery 

drop table #names
```

produces the same results for both selects:

```
    name
1   bob
2   jim
3   john
4   luke
5   mark
```

it's curious that select top 5 distinct is not valid, but select distinct top 5 is and works as you might expect select top 5 distinct to work.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` removes rows if *all* selected values are equal. Apparently, you have entries with the same `p.id` but with different `pl.nm` (or `pl.val` or `pl.txt_val`). The answer to your question depends on which one of these values you want to show in the *one* row with your `p.id` (the first? the smallest? any?).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you want one result for each p.id?

But you are getting "duplicate" results for some p.id's, is that right?

The DISTINCT keyword applies to the entire result set, so applies to pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val, not just p.id.

You need something like

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.id, max( p1.nm ), max (p1.val), ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY p.id
```

Won't need the distinct keyword then.

Comment: yes, but if you want one result per p.id, you'll have to do something arbitrary or leave off those columns entirely

Comment: Not necessarily, if you want the row that is associated with a specific row for each p.id, for example the one with the max(nm) or max(), you want the whole row, not random max values from potentially different rows.  The solution Paul Creasey gave has the potential to do this simply by changing the order by inside the over() clause.  Not sure what coward down-voted his answer without stating his/her reason(s).

Comment: Agreed, that's probably more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Common Table Expression to get the top 10 distinct ID's and then join those to the rest of your data:

```
;WITH TopTenIDs AS
( 
   SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 id
   FROM dm.labs 
   ORDER BY ......
)
SELECT 
    tti.id, pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val
FROM
    TopTenIDs tti
INNER JOIN
    dm.labs pl ON pl.id = tti.id
INNER JOIN 
    mas_data.patients p ON pl.id = p.id
WHERE
    pl.nm like '%LDL%'
    AND val IS NOT NULL
```

That should work. Mind you: if you have a "TOP x" clause, you typically also need an ORDER BY clause - if you want the TOP 10, you need to tell the system in what order that "TOP" is.

PS: why do you even join the "patients" table, if you never select any fields from it??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 14 A, B, C
  FROM MyDatabase
  Where EXISTS 
   (
     Select Distinct[A] FROM MyDatabase
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer and you can find 3 heights value from table

```
SELECT TOP(1)  T.id FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP(3) st.id  FROM Table1 AS t1 , Table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id ORDER BY (t2.id) DESC ) T ORDER BY(T.id) ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (

SELECT TOP 10 p.id, pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val

from dm.labs pl
join mas_data.patients p    
  on pl.id = p.id
  where pl.nm like '%LDL%'
  and val is not null

)
```

Comment: This will be applicable if you only want to remove duplicate data in (p.id, pl.nm, pl.val, pl.txt_val)