# SQL Select Count Distinct groupby

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I am looking to select the top 10 names that have watched the most unique shows. My_table is as follows:

```
Name     Show
Hilda    The Road
Tom      Joker
Harry    Rainbow Bright
Hilda    Show 100
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2008: TOP 10 and distinct together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925176/sql-server-2008-top-10-and-distinct-together)

Comment: Consider posting expected more detailed data and expected output. Also, what have you tried so far? What part of it worked and which didn't? Stackoverflow is not a free writing service.

Comment: What's the expected result in case of a tie in place 10? (I.e. 10th and 11th have the same number of watched, unique shows.)

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `LIMIT` here:

```
SELECT Name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Show) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```